# Compile NPM workspaces and app into a single distributible

Tags: node.js, npm, workspace

I have the following folder structure using NPM workspaces:

```
+-- package.json
+-- server (node)
   +-- package.json
+-- ui (react)
   +-- package.json
+-- packages
   +-- module_1
   |   +-- package.json
   +-- module_2
       +-- package.json
```

The idea is that I have a set of modules in the packages folder which are ultimately imported into the server folder (and other apps).

This works great when running `npm start` within the server folder but I now need to create a single folder which can be deployed to a server (e.g. Docker, etc).

Important note is that some modules are not used by the server and others are not used by the UI. E.g. I shouldn't have database dependencies installed on the UI project when compiling.

**Question**:
How do I create the single deployable folder for the server and/or UI which I can run independently?

Comment: which are all the WS you need to compile?